Evaluation of defined(x) in a `#pragma message` output string
For debugging purposes, I am trying to output information on whether certain symbols are defined, but without having to impair my code readability with too many #if defined() blocks. I tried using the defined() operator in text output by #pragma message like so:
#pragma message defined(__UNDERLAY__)

I was expecting this to output 1 if __UNDERLAY__ was defined, and 0 if it was not. But instead:
testbed_defines.c:61:9: warning: expected a string after ‘#pragma message’ [-Wpragmas]
   61 | #pragma message defined(__UNDERLAY__)
      |         ^~~~~~~

I tried to "stringify" like this:
#pragma message "" defined(__UNDERLAY__)

This only caused a different error:
testbed_defines.c:61:9: warning: junk at end of ‘#pragma message’ [-Wpragmas]
   61 | #pragma message "" defined(__UNDERLAY__)
      |         ^~~~~~~

I tried the concatenation operator:
testbed_defines.c:61:20: error: stray ‘##’ in program
   61 | #pragma message "" ## defined(__UNDERLAY__)
      |                    ^~
testbed_defines.c:61:9: warning: junk at end of ‘#pragma message’ [-Wpragmas]
   61 | #pragma message "" ## defined(__UNDERLAY__)
      |         ^~~~~~~

Is there a way to actually output the value of defined(x) without having to construct an #if block? Especially as that would need me to write the two valid values (0 and 1) into code like magic numbers. It looks as though defined simply isn't being evaluated here at all!

Why not put the #pragma inside an #ifdef?

Pragma is much compiler dependent. Some compilers expand messages, some don't. Different compiler do it differently. What compiler are you using?

@pts When there are a lot of these to check, a large number of #ifdef ... #endif blocks would impair code readability. And as I mentioned, I'd like to avoid having to hardcode the valid output values of define() as magic numbers.

@KamilCuk Good point. I'm using gcc and I've just added the [gcc] tag to clarify.

"Is there a way to actually output the value of defined(x) without having to construct an #if block?" No.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Section 6.10.1 of the C11 draft (N1570) describes defined() but doesn't say anything about it having to be in an #if block. Can you cite a source that supports your claim?

You can use any identifier anywhere. It just won't have the same meaning as in #if block. The section you reference describes the meaning of defined used in an #if block. Outside of one it is just a normal identifier.


Is there a way to actually output the value of defined(x) without having to construct an #if block?

No. defined() is only evaluated inside #if and #elif and such.
You could check if the macro expands to nothing with https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/detect-empty-macro-arguments/ .
It is not possible to expand to 1 or 0 depending  on if macro is defined Is there any way to convert a variable macro into 0 or 1 based on whether it is defined? .

Do you have a source for this? Section 6.10.1 of the C11 draft (N1570) describes defined() but doesn't say anything about #if or #ifelse.

@AJM: If you have seen defined described in C 2011 6.10.1, you have seen the title of that clause, which is “Conditional inclusion.” That clause is solely describing the conditional inclusion feature of preprocessing, which is the #if, #ifdef, #ifndef, #elif, #else, and #endif directives. The sentence that describes defined starts “The expression that controls conditional inclusion shall be…,” and it is in that context that defined is described. It is solely in the context of an expression controlling conditional inclusion.

@AJM: Re “… 6.10.1 … but doesn't say anything about #if or #ifelse”: That is bizarre. First, it is #elif, not #ifelse. Second, 6.10.1 contains six paragraphs. Mentions of #if appear in paragraphs 3, 4, and 5.

@EricPostpischil To clarify, section 6.10.1 paragraph 1 describes defined() but does not mention #if or #ifelse. The rest of the paragraphs aren't describing defined. I'd go back and edit that comment with this clarification, but I'm now past the 5 minute time limit.

Thinking about paragraphs 3 and 5 again in light of your comment... it is indeed starting to look like I can't do this and will have to accept this answer and move on.

@EricPostpischil Also, I mentioned #ifelse because this was mentioned in the answer. I didn't recognise it, but I was at least able to say that that part of C11 did not mention it.

Sorry, there is nothing clever you can do. The best you can do is
#ifdef __UNDERLAY_\
    #pragma message “__UNDERLAY is defined”
#else
    #pragma message “__UNDERLAY__ is not defined”
#endif

You can’t for example turn this into a macro. You can do a bit better if you have a macro that is guaranteed to be either undefined or defined with a non-zero integer value.
